# Can't Install DotConnect for PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, visual-studio, devart, dotconnect

I have "Incompatible version found" error with Details: "Devart.Data assembly version 5.0.1375.0 is found in Global Assembly Cache." When I'm running DotConnect for PostgreSQL v 7.4.521.0 Installation. But I have no any "Devart","DotConnect" etc assemblies in Global Assembly Cache.
How to fix it and install? Thanx.

Comment: Please look at this link... [link](http://forums.devart.com/viewtopic.php?t=21060). It discusses the same issue but with Oracle. It might help you out with you issue.

Answer (score 2):

Ed Mendez's link helped. I've used comment by Pinturiccio » Thu 26 Apr 2012 12:29
to enter C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\ folder via cmd and delete there all Devart* folders.